# Google.maps.Map Javascript API V3 compatibilty with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am trying to figure out why this will work by adding a map on a div of id="google_map"

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_map"), googleMapOptions);
```

but this wont work

```
var our_map = $("#google_map");
map = new google.maps.Map(our_map, googleMapOptions);
```

I get  this console error on firebug

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.


...(a,b,c){c=c&&1==b;Jt.H?Yn(a[w],c?"":b):(b="alpha(opacity="+Jd(100*b)+")",rn(a[w]...
```

Answer (score 5):

`Map` constructor expect `Node` as the first parameter: *Map(mapDiv:Node, opts?:MapOptions)*.

Instead of

```
map = new google.maps.Map(our_map, googleMapOptions);
```

you have to use

```
map = new google.maps.Map(our_map[0], googleMapOptions);
```